# advanced custom fields causing Internal server Error wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wp-graphql

I have an issue in my wordpress admin whereby when i execute a wpgraphl query in the IDE, i get internal server error, if i deactivate my acf plugin, the query executes and returns data but when i activate ACF plugin, i get internal server error 500. i have tried updating wpgraphql plugin, and ACF plugin but still getting same error.

```
{
  "code": "internal_server_error",
  "message": "<p>There has been a critical error on this website.</p><p><a href=\"https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/faq-troubleshooting/\">Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress.</a></p>",
  "data": {
    "status": 500
  },
  "additional_errors": []
}
```

Comment: Look at your server error logs. That will tell you exactly what is happening.